# How to specifiy "precision" when sorting on date fields in Elasticsearch?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have a field of type `date` (input format `epoch_second`) in my Elasticsearch mapping (I'm using ES 2.1). I know that I can sort on that field like

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
       "myDateField" : {
         "order": "desc"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

But this sorts in seconds precision. I'd like to sort by "week interval" (7 day intervals backward from now) and within the same week by score again, like this (pseduocode):

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
       "myDateField" : {
         "order"     : "desc",
         "precision" : "week"
        }
    },
    "_score"
  ]
}
```

So, all hits being within the last 7 days should be ranked equally, all hits older than 7 days and younger than 14 days in the next "sort group" and so on. And each "week group" should be sorted by score again.

In words: "What are the most relevant (to the current query) documents from the last 7 days (but don't filter out older ones completly)?"

Background: An event search, where obviously more recent events should matter most.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It look likes you are trying to make something like Group BY in sql, its equally aggregation in elastic search how about check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html this one ?

Comment: But aggregations don't support paging because of performance reasons (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915).

Comment: It is really a workaround, there may be better solution for you by sorting but if it is attracts you anyway just check that comment it looks nice https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915#issuecomment-69942916

Comment: Would my case be possible by scripting? I never used scripting, so I have no idea if this is possible and how much features the whole scripting functionality provides. I remember seeing examples where people sorted on a script acting on a field instead sorting on this field directly.

Comment: Sure by scripting you can solve your problem even with specific details. You may add also dates as a week pointer in ES. Then you can aggregate data by week with language which you use. Group By cannot be achieved by Sort By I think. So scripting would solve the problem if data is not big to loop inside for performance concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read about scripted sorting and this is my solution which works for me:

```
{
  "sort": [
    "_script": {
      "lang": "expression",
      "type": "number",
      "script": "doc['myDateField'].value - doc['myDateField'].value % 604800000"
      "order": "desc"
    },
    "_score"
  ]
}
```

What I'm doing here is dividing my date field by the desired span expressed in milliseconds (Elasticsearch stores a date field internally as `long` which maps to milliseconds) and taking the remainder. Then substracting the remainder from the actual date. This way all dates are truncated to "0 am on (0 to 6) days before". This way all documents in the same 7-day-interval will then have the same timestamp and are sorted equally according to it. And finally I append the regular score sorting as the second order condition.

I'm not sure how the performance scales on this solution, but for my few thousand documents that need this sorting I was unable to notice any delay over non-sorting.

Answer (score 4):

You may find a [decay function on a function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay) useful in your situation. It is specifically designed to adjust the score of a document the "further away" one of its fields is from some defined starting point.

This works with dates as well as numbers and geo point fields. It accepts an `origin` option which sets the reference date from which other documents will be compared. Conveniently, if you don't provide an origin for a date field, it defaults to the current date (which should work for your scenario).

You would probably want to set your `offset` to 7 days. That way, all documents for the last 7 days will be scored equally. Outside of that range, the score begins to drop, depending on the decay function you use.

Try something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "field1": "search goes here"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "exp": {
            "myDateField": {
              "offset": "7d", 
              "scale": "14d",
              "decay": 0.5
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```